# sIFR font sizing problems

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr

I'm trying to render a font using sifr to about 160px in size, but it seems to stop expanding anything larger than half of what i require. i've tried setting the font-size in the sifr-config and css. but to no avail it still won't get any larger.

Any ideas?

My example page is here:
http://oonagi.org/sifr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sIFR stops after 160px or so. I believe originally because Flash wouldn't render larger font sizes, but I can't quite remember.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the following to your h4 css directly following font-size:

```
line-height: 1em;
```

This should make your line height the equivalent of your font-size, perhaps fixing the height issue.

http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/font-sizing

Comment: I've tried adding line-height to my css and sifr-config but it's still not updating the size.

i'm applying the css to just my screen css not the sifr.css file.